# See history of a merged branch

Tags: git, git-log

Given a history like this:

1. create new branch foo at commit a111
2. add 3 commits to foo (b222, c333, d444)
3. merge foo into master (e555)

Is there a sequence of arguments to `git log ... e555` which would select b222 to d444? (Also selecting a111 or e555is ok).

(Ok, I think I can self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of trial and error, I figured it out:

```
e555^1..e555^2
```

In other words "select commits that are in the history of the second parent of the merge [the branch] but not in the history of the first parent [master, normally]".

I don't suppose there is a simpler way?